# How to get the PrimaryKey value of the newly added record?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am working on Winforms applications and binding the SQL data source through designer. i need to get the proper primary key value of the newly added record. if the last PK value was 10 and added or removed some rows,  then dataset generated PK value would be 11 while the real PK value in SQL server would be 14. Please suggest me any ideas.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Refer [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsdata/2009/09/15/refresh-the-primary-key-identity-column-during-insert-operation/)

Comment: @Prithiv Please mark answer as accepted by clicking the green tick aside it. and if you found it useful you may also want to up-vote it. thank you

Comment: Hi @Bala.. i'm trying to get it from grid's event. Is it posssible to use SCOPE_IDENTITY in my grid application.

Comment: `this.Validate();
this.dataTableBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.dataTableTableAdapter.Update(dataSourceDataSet);
` by this code i have updated the newly added record from my grid to SQL

Comment: @Prithiv SCOPE_IDENTITY use at Sql server end. (so, you can use it on sql query). Please refer the link that I have added into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you can write the SQL clause yourself, you can use the [OUTPUT clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx). Works both for insert and update.

e.g.

```
INSERT AValueColumnName
OUTPUT PrimaryKeyColumnName
INTO mytable
VALUES (1)
```